# Issues with pagination in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

I am trying to implementation the same pagination that is used in the NerdDinner ASP.NET. I am receiving the following error in my view, whenever the pagination starts to kick in.

> "A route named 'Index' could not be
>   found in the route collection."

The error is happening on Line 64.

```
Line 62:         <% if (this.Model.HasNextPage)
Line 63:            { %>
Line 64:         <%= this.Html.RouteLink("Next Page >>>", "Index", new { page = (this.Model.PageIndex + 1) })%>
Line 65:         <% } %>
Line 66:     </div>
```

My controller code is:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    const int pageSize = 25;

    var topics = this.TopicRepository.FindAllTopics();
    var paginatedTopics = new PaginatedList<Topic>(topics, page ?? 0, pageSize);

    return this.View(paginatedTopics);
}
```

My view code is ...

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CreativeLogic.Sauron.WebMvc.Helpers.PaginatedList<CreativeLogic.Sauron.WebMvc.Models.Topic>>" %>

<!-- Code to display the list here -->

<div class="pagination">
    <% if (this.Model.HasPreviousPage)
       { %>
    <%= this.Html.RouteLink("<<< Previous Page", 
                           "Index", new { page = (this.Model.PageIndex - 1) }) %>
    <% } %>
    <% if (this.Model.HasNextPage)
       { %>
    <%= this.Html.RouteLink("Next Page >>>", 
                           "Index", new { page = (this.Model.PageIndex + 1) })%>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

This is my first attempt at doing the pagination in ASP.NET MVC ... if there is a better way, please let me know, otherwise, where am I going wrong here?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use RouteLink (which takes a route name) but instead use an ActionLink which takes an action name like Index.

Comment: That did the trick! Wonder why and how they are using RouteLink in the NerdDinner example?

Answer (score 2):

Well the RouteLink Extension Method looks for a defined route with the name of "Index" in the Global.asax, and by default there is just 1 route defined in the Global the "Default", it looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default",                                              // Route name
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Maybe as HakonB said you must use the ActionLink Extension Method or define a route in the Global asax for the pagination.